# how to collapse all function on for each angular UI tree

Tags: angularjs

For Angular ui-tree, i want to add expland all or collapse all.

I tried the following code and it works.

```
 $scope.collapseAll = function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('angular-ui-tree:collapse-all');
      };

  $scope.expandAll = function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('angular-ui-tree:expand-all');
  };
  ...
```

The question is,my page have multiple ui tree, i only want to trigger expandAll function for separate. now i trigger this expandAll function. **ALL** ui -tree will be affected.

Is there any solution to set each one as seperate?

[How to call collapseAll function on Angular UI tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562900/how-to-call-collapseall-function-on-angular-ui-tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check at the [Source](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/blob/master/source/directives/uiTreeNode.js) of angular ui tree , the `'angular-ui-tree:collapse-all'` event toggles a scope value . Other problem being each of the directives in angular-ui-tree inherits the scope of the parent than having a isolated scope . So changing the when you broadcast an event it is actually changing the same scope value .

You should either find a way for each tree's to have a separate scope or think of using some other tree's like [v-accordion](http://lukaszwatroba.github.io/v-accordion/) .

Comment: Thanks your reply. v-accordion is a fantastic plugin, later will consider to use it. anyway, i use while loop and get childNode recursively, can solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we should broadcast angular-ui-tree:collapse-all for specified tree scope.
It's work for me.you can use it without any hesitation at all.

```
    function collapseAll() {
        var treeScope = _getRootNodesScope('myTreeId');
        if (treeScope) {
            treeScope.$broadcast('angular-ui-tree:collapse-all');
        }
    }


 function expandAll() {
        var treeScope = _getRootNodesScope('userTreeroot');
        if (treeScope) {
            treeScope.$broadcast('angular-ui-tree:expand-all');
        }
    }

  function _getRootNodesScope(myTreeId) {
 var treeElement = angular.element(document.getElementById(myTreeId));
 if (treeElement) {
 var treeScope = (typeof treeElement.scope === 'function') ? 
 treeElement.scope() : undefined;
            return treeScope;
        }
        return undefined;
    };
```